# How to plot a scatter plot using the histogram output in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to plot a scatter plot similar to this one :

[image]

I can plot a histogram from my data but i want a scatter plot for the same data . Is there any way i can use the hist() method output as an input to scatter plot? or some other way is there to plot scatter plot using the hist() method in matplotlib? 
The code is use to plot histogram is as follows :

```
data = get_data()
plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
ax = plt.subplots()
plt.hist(data,histtype='bar',bins = 100,log=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16496996/832621), there is a code to plot 2D or 3D histograms...

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for the following:

Essentially `plt.hist()` outputs two arrays (and as Nordev pointed out some patches). The first is the count in each bin (`n`) and the second the edges of the bin.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# Create some example data
y = np.random.normal(5, size=1000)

# Usual histogram plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(y, bins=50)  # output is two arrays

# Scatter plot
# Now we find the center of each bin from the bin edges
bins_mean = [0.5 * (bins[i] + bins[i+1]) for i in range(len(n))]
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.scatter(bins_mean, n)
```

[image: Example]

This is the best I can think of without some more description of the problem. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: The `output` consists not only of two arrays, but also a list of `Patch` objects. Why not use the "standard" `n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(...` as this unpacks the returned arrays/list to the respective variables? IMO these are more intuitive variable names and makes it easier to read the code.

Comment: If you don't want the patches, just use `np.histogram`.  `plt.hist` is just a wrapper around `histogram` that plots the result using `plt.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

I built on these ideas and increased the number of bins a lot. With a large number of bins, the small values on the graph don't get drowned out and you can see data shapes better.  Since I had multiple peaks in the data I wanted to remove empty bins. I changed those values to float('nan') which holds a place but doesn't get plotted and keeps the graph cleaner. The graph is used to show variances in decoded data values (y) around integer points.

```
counts, bins = np.histogram(y, bins=10000)
counts = [n if n > 0 else float('nan') for n in counts]
pl.scatter(bins[:len(counts)],counts)
pl.xticks(range(12),range(12))
pl.grid()
pl.show()
```

[image: Zero crossing variances for multiple bit lengths]